# PHP insert textarea with semicolone into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a form in php that has a title and description area.
When I submit the form and try to insert the data to MYSQL I get an error wich seems to be due to a semicolon in the title.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near *'s Club', 
>   'Design and Develop', '1')' at line 1*

## Query

```
INSERT INTO Projects (ID, Title, Description, Status) 
        VALUES (0, 'Women's Club', 'Description of Project', '1')
```

Im trying to use mysql_real_escape_string() but im still getting this error.

Is there another method I need to be using to allow for semicolons to be inserted into mysql?

Here is some of the code im using.

```
$desc =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);

$q = "INSERT INTO Projects (ID, Title, Description, Status) 
           VALUES (0, '$title', '$desc', '1')";
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not with your `$desc`. Instead it is with your `$title`.

Add this line too:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
```

just before insert query.

**ON A SIDE NOTE**: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mysqli_` or `PDO` with bound parameters. `mysql_` functions are deprecated and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Just make sure magic quotes are disabled.

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO Projects (ID, Title, Description, Status)  VALUES (0, ?, ?, 1)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $title, $desc);

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're injecting *yourself* apparently.  The title also needs to be escaped.

Your code is highly insecure.  Don't use `mysql_*` and don't leave your queries unparameterized (they need to be sanitized)!

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', $username, $password);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Projects VALUES (null, ?, ?, 1)");
$stmt->execute($title, $desc);
```

In case `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled, use `stripslashes` on the POST scalar values.  This doesn't affect security, but if you don't do it your row will have extra slashes.

Comment: +1 Sad that providing a correct alternative gets no recognition.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add slashes to special mysql chars.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: No, the proper escape function is `mysql_real_escape_string()` (Although the `mysql_*` functions should not be used any more.)